# Folder analyzer that shows duration of audio/video files

Tags: hard-disk

I have a folder with a bunch of subfolders. Each of these subfolders contains either some audio (mp3) or video (mkv) files. I would like to know the total duration of audio and video files per each subfolder. Is there a folder analyzer or maybe media player that can do that?

Comment: See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the dual pane file manager [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) can do this together with the [MediaTime](https://totalcmd.net/plugring/MediaTime.html) plugin.

This screenshot from the MediaTime plugin shows how that can look:

[image]